# Purpose of `jshint globalstrict: true` with 'use strict'

Tags: javascript, jshint

Often while reading JavaScript source code I see these two lines together on the top.

```
/* jshint globalstrict: true */
'use strict';
```

Now, I very well know the purpose of `'use strict';`. 
Can someone enlighten me why `jshint globalstrict` is included ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) (forked from [JSLint](http://jslint.com/)) is a popular "[lint checker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software))" that's run on JavaScript code. It doesn't execute or modify the code, but analyzes it and reports a variety of different *potential* errors or bad practices that it finds.

If you have `'use strict';` at the top of your JavaScript file, outside of any JavaScript functions, it will enable strict mode for the entire file. By default, JSHint will report a warning if it sees this.

```
'use strict';

window.permissions = null;

function initialize() {
  window.permissions = 0;
}
```

```
Warnings
1: Use the function form of "use strict".
```

This is because many people automatically concatenate their JavaScript files together before sending them to the user, and in those cases the top-level `'use strict;'` can cause bugs. For example, if you have `'use strict';` at the top of `main.js`, and it's concatenated with the non-strict-mode `controls.js`, strict mode will unintentionally also be applied to the code from `controls.js`, potentially changing its behaviour.

```
// This code is fine on its own, but will break if strict mode is applied.
document.querySelector('.upgade').onclick = function() {
  window.permissions = 0777;
}
```

If this could happen in your case, you should avoid `'use strict';` at the top-level of your file. You could the entire file [in a self-executing function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592396/1114) to avoid side-effects of concatenation.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  window.permissions = null;

  function initialize() {
    window.permissions = 0;
  }
}());
```

However, if you're sure that you don't need to worry about concatenation and don't want to modify your code, the [`globalstrict`](http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/#globalstrict) option for JSHint will disable this warning. It's [also possible](http://www.jshint.com/docs/) to specify JSHint options using a `.jshintrc` file or the `--config` command-line flag,  but in many cases the this "inline configuration" you saw—using a comment in the file—is easiest.

```
/* jshint globalstrict: true */
```

Comment: so globalstrict: true will supress warnings that 'use strict' would have otherwise reported ?

Comment: Pretty much. It will suppress warnings that JSHint would have otherwise reported *about* 'use strict'.